# How do I create an identity matrix of arbitrary size in Java?

Tags: java, math, linear-algebra

Is there a utility to create an identity matrix of specified size in Java?

Comment: How is this not someone asking for university homework?

Comment: It's even tagged with don't-come-near-me...

Comment: @Justin, I tried to turn the question into something a little more useful and less homework-y.

Answer (score 6):

Try [Apache Commons Math for commonly used linear algebra](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/MatrixUtils.html#createRealIdentityMatrix(int)):

```
// Set dimension to the size of the square matrix that you would like
// Example, this will make a 3x3 matrix with ones on the diagonal and
// zeros elsewhere.
int dimension = 3;
RealMatrix identity = RealMatrix.createRealIdentityMatrix(dimension);
```

Comment: It is now `RealMatrix identity = MatrixUtils.createRealIdentityMatrix(dimension);`.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to use a 2 dimensional array to represent the matrix and no 3rd party libraries:

```
public class MatrixHelper {
  public static double[][] getIdentity(int size) {
    double[][] matrix = new double[size][size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) matrix[i][i] = 1;
    return matrix;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would only loop the diagonal as `new double` already creates a zero-filled array... despite not being a *great* difference.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger .. good idea. 5 years later, I've updated my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [Jama](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) for all your matrix needs.  There's a call to generate an [identity matrix](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/Jama/Matrix.html) (see the [identity method](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/Jama/Matrix.html#identity%28int,%20int%29)).

Answer (score 1):

A memory-efficient solution would be to create a class like so:

```
public class IdentityMatrix{
     private int dimension;

     public IdentityMatrix(int dimension){
          this.dimension=dimension
     }

     public double getValue(int row,int column){
          return row == column ? 1 : 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need the constructor and the private variable though.., and you can make getValue static.